# C# compiler sees Fluent syntax or Query Expression?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I'm always confusing about this stuff.

I have this query :

```
string[] names = { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Mary", "Jay" };

IEnumerable<string> query = names.Where(n => n.Contains("a"))
.OrderBy(n => n.Length)
.Select(n => n.ToUpper());
```

I've read in a [book](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=VENrFSQFco8C&pg=PA321&lpg=PA321&dq=%22The%20compiler%20processes%20a%20query%20expression%20by%20translating%20it%20into%20fluent%20syntax%22&source=bl&ots=3uU_jhbWaV&sig=UqpY2LeX_k-pjENl1hOlNPqbYlo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=elBmT7G0BuLf4QTf172fCA&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22The%20compiler%20processes%20a%20query%20expression%20by%20translating%20it%20into%20fluent%20syntax%22&f=false) that:

> The compiler processes a query expression by translating it into
>   fluent syntax

But in Reflector I see the opposite: 
[image: Reflector Code]

This is not fluent syntax.

So what does the compiler sees?

Comment: Reflector shows you what it wants you to see.

Comment: You should have looked with ildasm ;)

Comment: @sixlettervariables so `The compiler processes a query expression by translating it into fluent syntax.` does it mean that The IL is build based on Fluent syntax ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: as it is currently written my understanding is it is realized as Expressions and then realized as the fluent methods. This isn't always the case as with Linq to Entities or Linq to SQL. They could very well in the future do direct Query syntax to IL conversion. Nothing is stopping those crazy compiler writers but time and effort.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: a very vague question with no sence. -1.

Comment: @Tigran i guess you didnt open the linq.  i can handle with your -1.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Not clear what you're searching for, for others too. All here more or less respond the same thing, but you continue for searching of something else (fluent syntax), which doesn't actually exist. This is my reasoning.

Comment: @Tigran my question was from reading a book. thats all. in the book it says that the compiler translate it to a certain flow rather than the other one. and my mistake was the way i look at reflector and now i know how. still though , I would like to see where can that the compiler sees it as "fluent"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A "compiler" is by definition a device which translates a text written in one language into another language.

The C# compiler logically translates C# programs that contain query expressions into C#-without-query-expressions, and then translates *those* programs into IL.  (Note that it need not *actually* do that middle stage of translation; it must *behave* as though it does so, but if the compiler writers are clever enough to skip that intermediate step and still get the right output then we certainly can do so.)

Reflector is also a compiler. It translates IL into C#. How it does so is it's business.

You can't make any conclusions about what the C# compiler does based on the output of Reflector; they are completely different programs written by different people to solve different problems.

Comment: Is part of the reason to skip the middle step to avoid having to maintain two codebases? Or was this born from supporting L2S/L2EF?

Comment: Hi Eric , so  - (According to the attached link) `the compiler process aquery expression by translating it into fluent syntax` and then writes its `IL` ? is it correct ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, that's correct. Query expressions are just "syntactic sugar" for the fluent form.  The C# specification has a section that describes exactly what the tranformation is if you're interested.

Answer (score 6):

Query comprehension syntax is compiled directly into method calls; they produce indistinguishable IL.

However, many decompilers will always translate LINQ calls into query comprehension syntax.
YOu can probably change that behavior in Options.

Comment: where can i see that it actually translate to fluent syntax ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: In ildasm, or by disabling that option in Reflector.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: there is no concept of "fluent syntax". I suppose it's just a expression of book's author.

Comment: @SLaks there is no such option there. only to IL and its deferentially not clear ...:)

Answer (score 3):

The stock `csc` compiler converts any and all syntax into IL, fluent or otherwise. What you're looking at is the reconstruction chosen by Reflector.

Certain syntax is simply sugar for more complicated constructs *under the hood*, and the [query expressions are one of these examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx). Other examples includes [foreach loops](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter6/iteratorblockimplementation.aspx) and [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Now if this is LINQ to SQL or Entities, the query syntax and fluent syntax is realized as Expressions and translated by the provider under the hood. This is not the same as in L2O.

Comment: where can i see that it actually translate to fluent syntax ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: what do you mean? The compiler outputs IL regardless in the Linq to Objects scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are reading this backwards (but I could be mistaken)

What it is saying is that

```
from n in names
where n.Contains("a")
orderby n.Length
select n.ToUpper()
```

Translates into

```
names
.Where(n => n.Contains("a"))
.OrderBy(n => n.Length)
.Select(n => n.ToUpper());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think saying "fluent syntax" book means the [Deferred Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx) of LINQ queires. 
When only on actual request of the data the query is generated based on all queries done before (if there is any). All queries done before are analyzed and one single (if it's possible) optimized LINQ query generated to get a data.

From the final result point of view, like others mantioned, it always ends up into the set of `IL` instructions.